# new formdata dinamico pasarle parametro dinamico

Tags: javascript, jquery

como puedo hacerlo dinamico?
si tengo 3 formularios el primero me lo recibe sin problema pero los otros dos no los recibe

```
data: new FormData($("#guardar")[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que ciclar tus formularios. Puedes hacer un arreglo de formularios con sus respectivos ID´s, o puedes darles una clase a todos y ciclar la clase.

Te dejo un ejemplo ciclando la clase.

```js
//Event cuando de click al botón
$(document).on('click','#btn',function(){
  var arr = [];
  //Recorremos todos los formularios
  $('.forms').each(function(){
    //Saca el formData del formulario actual
    arr.push( {data: new FormData( $(this) )} );
  });
  
  console.log( arr );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="forms" method="POST" action="foo.php">
  <input type="text" name="foo">
</form>

<form class="forms" method="POST" action="bar.php">
  <input type="text" name="bar">
</form>

<form class="forms" method="POST" action="poo.php">
  <input type="text" name="poo">
</form>
<input type="button" value="Guardar todos" id="btn">
```

Answer (score 0):

ya quedo 
en el boton pongo el parametro del ID del formulario en este caso es guardar1, en el otro seria guardar2

```
<button type="button" id="2" onclick="guardar('<?php echo 'guardar1'?>','<?php echo base64_encode('guardar')?>');">Guardar</button>


function guardar(g,f){
$(".loader").fadeIn("fast", function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?f='+f,
        data: new FormData($("#"+g)[0]),
        type:  'post',
        cache:false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success:  function(resultado){
            if(resultado === "OK"){
                $("#pMensajeCorrecto").html("Registro guardado");
                $("#divMensajeCorrecto").show();
                modalPrincipal.modal("hide");
                setTimeout(function(){cerrar("divMensajeCorrecto");}, 3000);
                $('#tabla').click();
                $(window).scrollTop(0);
            }
            else{
                $("#pMensajeModal").html(resultado);
                $("#divMensajeModal").show();
                setTimeout(function(){cerrar("divMensajeModal");}, 3000);
                $("#divGuardar").scrollTop(0);
            }
            $(".loader").fadeOut("fast");
        },
    });
});
```

}